# Selecting specific element in vue 2 inside v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Please see the code

```
<div  v-for="msg in leftMsg">
   div v-if="msg.last_sender"   @click.prevent="loadMsg(msg)">
    <tr :class="['active',{ 'seens' : !msg.seen, 'selected':msg.isActive}]">
      // some html
    </tr>
   </div>
</div>

loadMsg(obj){
    obj.isActive = !obj.isActive;
}
```

The problem is, it is adding selected class properly but when I click another item it adds selected but doesn't remove the old one. How can I keep only the most recent clicked item selected?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a data property outside of the `msg` objects and use that to track the active message.

```
data(){
  return {
    activeMessage: null,
    ...
  }
}
```

Then in your template, set the `activeMessage`.

```
<div  v-for="msg in leftMsg">
   <div v-if="msg.last_sender" @click.prevent="activeMessage = msg">
    <tr :class="['active',{ 'seens' : !msg.seen, 'selected': msg === activeMessage}]">
      // some html
    </tr>
   </div>
</div>
```

The key parts I changed here are `@click.prevent="activeMessage = msg"` and `'selected': msg === activeMessage`. This will set `activeMessage` to the clicked message, and then the `selected` class will be applied to the `activeMessage` and will *only* apply to the `activeMessage`.

I would also note that it's strange that you have a `tr` element nested inside `div`. I assume it was just because of your example, but that's not technically valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using a for loop. I thought it may help some other. 
In order to remove the all other previous active classes all you need to run a for loop and make them false and then assign active=true to the newest one.

Here is the code that may help

```
       // make all other selected class false first
            for(let i=0; i<this.leftMsg.length; i++){
                    this.leftMsg[i].isActive=false;

             }
           /*now making the newest one active*/
            obj.isActive = true;
```