# Vue js toggle class inside a loop

Tags: vue.js

I have a template like this :

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in inventory" v-on:click="say()" v-bind:class="{active:isActive}" > {{ item.name }} - ${{ item.price }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And from my "controller" :

```
var vm = new Vue({
 el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    inventory: [
      {name: 'MacBook Air', price: 1000},
      {name: 'MacBook Pro', price: 1800},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Acer Aspire One', price: 300}
   ],
    isActive : false
 },
  methods: {
    say: function () {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive 
    }
 }
```

});

With this when i click one item from the list, all items are affected to active class. My question is how to toggle individual element?

Thank you.

Comment: Some version of this question comes up constantly here.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45486192/38065) is one answer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46876697/38065) is another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting specific element in vue 2 inside v-for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486192/selecting-specific-element-in-vue-2-inside-v-for-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a active flag on each item to be able to track them individually.

For example:

```
{name: 'MacBook Air', price: 1000, isActive: false},
{name: 'MacBook Pro', price: 1800, isActive: true}
```

You will then will be able to bind the class and click event to item.isActive by doing something like this:

```
<li v-for="item in inventory" v-on:click="item.isActive = !item.isActive" v-bind:class="{active:item.isActive}" > {{ item.name }} - ${{ item.price }}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if class name contains dash "-" vue can't comile the template.
I tried with class with this name "main-container" and face this issue.